# docker-compose Windows Powershell tags

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, docker-compose, pull

I'm new with docker-compose through PowerShell, I'm trying to do a pull specifying TAGS, but I don't know the correct syntax to do it. This is a simple line that I'm trying to run.

```
1_TAG=test TAG=develop docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml pull
```

It does not work like it would under a bash console. I've tried to declare them as variables point docker to use them but it didn't recognize it.

I'm running everything from the path where I have my *.yml files and project folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By just setting the $env: variable solves the issue, thanks.